# My gas sensor is stuck physically, how can I fix it?

Tags: gas

I'm not sure if this is the right area, but it's a problem with one of my components physically.

[image]

When I press on both sides, it doesn't come up. Is there any way that I can get this 'up' cosmetically without taking it apart? Thanks!

Comment: No it's not the right area (but don't know what would be though) but I can make a suggestion anyway. Have you tried to pull it back with a piece of sticky tape or duct tape ? If that doesn't work I would try some hot-melt (from a glue gun), put some in the dent, let it cool then try to carefully pull it off.

Comment: I think that stuff is metal mesh, like a microphone. You might be able to make get a small steel wire and make a small hook and pull it up. Otherwise get a new sensor, if your time is worth anything you'll probably spend more time messing with this than a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Typically that's stainless-steel mesh. I suggest an inexpensive (many of them come from Pakistan or India) set of [dental picks](http://bhagattool.com/pick-set-01.htm), just hook it where it got bashed in and gently try to pull it out. They are quite useful tools to have around anyway.

[image]

If this is a combustible gas detector, keep in mind that part of the purpose of the mesh is to make the sensor explosion-proof by cooling a flame front below the ignition temperature so if you leave a hole you may have compromised the safety.